# Fetching data through ajax and then apply filter using select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have 3 different select menu: 1.Category 2.State 3.City

I am using ajax to fetch the data on "#searchresult" by using jquery on change method that send data on PHP.

Fetching is going properly but only for one "select" option.

What I want is when user change another "select" option, it will update the current "#searchresult" fetched data. 
Like: Suppose, on changing "category" to "car", it fetch all the data of "cars" on "#searchresult" and now on "state" change to "new york", it update the "#searchresult" that are in new york.

I tried many different approches like using multiple if statements to find whether the select is choosen or not, but reached no where.

Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#category").change(function() {

    var data = $("#category option:selected").val();
    var category = $("#category option:selected").text();

    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('id');
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "category",
      data: {
        data: data
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $("#searchresult").html("");

        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
          $("#searchresult").append('<div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 merchant" style="background-image: url(https://im.proptiger.com/1/1543935/6/green-villa-elevation-7990949.jpeg?width=380&height=285);">    <div class="filter"></div>     <span class="category">' + category + '</span>     <div class="col align-self-end">     <p>' + response.contractor[i].first_name + '</p>     <span>' + response.contractor[i].city_name + ',' + response.contractor[i].state_name + '</span>     </div>    <div class="slideup">     <p>More info?</p>     <a href="' + response.contractor[i].url + '" class="btn">Profile</a>    </div>   </div>');
        }
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="category" id="category" class="chosen">
<option value="0" default>category</option>
<option value="1">Car</option>
<option value="2">Van</option>
</select>

<select name="state" id="state" class="chosen">
<option value="0" default>state</option>
<option value="1">Any</option>
<option value="2">other</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city" class="chosen">
<option value="0" default>city</option>
<option value="1">New york</option>
<option value="2">Chicago</option>
</select>

<div id="searchresult"></div>
```

and PHP is sending data in the form of json.

Thanks

Comment: what does url value?Not category,it must be the server uri.On hitting that uri,you will get result.

Comment: @hameedSyed I m using local host and the domain is 127.0.0.1:8000/category

Comment: As per the code you have provided, you have only 1 on-change event for the category. What you should be doing is to either let the user select all 3 values and trigger a on-change event when all the 3 values are selected or fire change for each select element and pass the other select values to your server to fetch the relevant data from your DB.

Comment: @RahulViswanath I actually want to fetch and update the result for each select statement. I tried if statement but failed; and now I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: @user5745970 could you confirm if the url 127.0.0.1:8000/category is the only 1 used to fetch all the required data? Or do you have separate urls for category, state and city?

Comment: @RahulViswanath No, I was trying to use 3 different URLs for all the 3 select boxes ie.. /category for category /state for state and /city or city. The PHP code is working fine and returning JSON output.                                                                       Even the jQuery fetching data is working fine, only I don't get any idea "how to create the filter for other select options, like I mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user5745970 here is sample fiddle I created to give you an idea on what needs to be done. Link to the fiddle is below

The idea is to have 3 different change events for each of your select and trigger a call to your server. What you need to do is send the other select values as data if selected. For example, if you're changing the City when the category is already selected, you need to send both category and city to your server to get you the response. If all 3 server side calls return the same JSON structure, then you can have only 1 success and error callback.

Do change the urls, method types and callbacks accordingly to match what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var category = '';
  var state = '';
  var city = '';
  $("#category").on('change', function() {
    category = $("#category option:selected").text();
    // here you need to check if state or city is selected, you need to send those values as the data to your server
  ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'GET', category, handleCategorySuccess, handleCategoryError)
  });
  
  $("#state").on('change', function() {    
    state = $("#state option:selected").text();    
    // here you need to check if category or city is selected, you need to send those values as the data to your server
  ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'GET', state, handleStateSuccess, handleStateError)
  });
  
  $("#city").on('change', function() {
    city = $("#city option:selected").text();    
    // here you need to check if state or category is selected, you need to send those values as the data to your server
  ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'GET', city, handleCitySuccess, handleCityError)
  });

});

var ajax = function(url, method, data, successCallBack, errorCallBack) { 
 $.ajax({
      type: method,
      url: url,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: successCallBack,
      error: errorCallBack
  });
}

function handleCategorySuccess(response) {
 alert(response);
}

function handleCategoryError() {
 alert('error');
}

function handleStateSuccess(response) {
 alert(response);
}

function handleStateError() {
 alert('error');
}

function handleCitySuccess(response) {
 alert(response);
}

function handleCityError() {
 alert('error');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" id="category" class="chosen">
  <option value="0" default>category</option>
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="2">Van</option>
</select>

<select name="state" id="state" class="chosen">
  <option value="0" default>state</option>
  <option value="1">Any</option>
  <option value="2">other</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city" class="chosen">
  <option value="0" default>city</option>
  <option value="1">New york</option>
  <option value="2">Chicago</option>
</select>

<div id="searchresult"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvrahul66/ez5a19ej/14/)